# Jenkins - Pre-build event

Tags: jenkins

How is that possible to add `Pre-Build` actions in **Jenkins**, exactly like it's `Post-Build` ?

I've came across `Conditional BuildStep`, `Run Condition` and `Parameterized Trigger` plugins, but can't find out a way to add that.

Comment: Can yo please clarify what you mean? What do you expect to happen there?  Also note you can use “stage” as a wrapper for steps

Comment: Do you mean to execute steps before the git checkout? There is no pre-build event because not every pipeline may build something.

Comment: @mkemmerz yes, i wanted that, thanks! you can post it as answer, and i'll accept it.

Comment: @kbry thanks for responding, i am new to Jenkins, and probably my question was not well formed in terms of Jenkins steps. I'll make a clarification and let you know then. tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there is no real pre-build event because not every pipeline may build something.

You can disable the default checkout by using the option [skipDefaultCheckout](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) and manually do the git checkout later using the command [checkout scm](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/). I think this is the closes you will get to reach a `Pre-Build-Stage`.